# Could I make Automatic Backup Folder For All new files I create or download?

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, 12.10, scripts, backup

I want to make a folder for all the new files I create , some times I create them at different places (e.g Desktop , Download , Document   etc )

**The Question Why would I do that ?
and The Answer Is**

I always Try a New Things Especially new OS and because I always write the observation and notes every where on that new Os , as an example I may write a doc at desktop then I may write and save another one At Document Folder and I may Download a doc or learn pic at any time , some times and suddenly some thing goes wrong and my OS fall , so I start to get all what I made out of that OS and of course that take time and not 100% accurate

Because Of that I want To make an Idea To make a Folder at another partation to contain another copy for all what I make work automatically without a single click waste of time

```
Note 
I don't want to make a backup for all OS because I may forget to make before OS fail
```

Comment: possible yes, efficient = no. since you have to crawl the whole system and sort your items by date modified etc. thats not a good idea. Better simply use one folder for the needed things and backup whenever you think a backup is needed.

Comment: I think all possible places are Desktop Document Pictures Downloads, videos , and aether I always want to backup Bookmark from firefox an mails from thunderbaird and Archive folder for packages and bash_history and logs

Answer (score 0):

You could in setting you can chosen a automatic backup, and all so of specified folders like document, download and desktop daily, weekly or months, am folders all so  push setting and backup, and then manged backup by you self, and it might work fine this way.